# DAX: Calculate time spent from one stop to other with respect to zipcode

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-wrangling

I need to calculate the time spent from one stop to another.
If the trip takes place in the same zipcode area and greater than one hour, I should report it.

For example,

The attached image with the dataframe shows the instance when arrivedTime from one stop to other in same zipcode has difference greater than one hour. I signal it. If it is less than one hour, no action needed. It should be grouped by and order by RuteID, Sequence and arrivedTime. In the attached example, the trip from zipCode 2300 to 2300 takes less then one hour it is ok. But If it is greater than one hour I should report by new column true/false for the number greater than one hour.

[image: example]

Comment: Please edit your question and add an example of your desired output.

Comment: Hi msta42a , thanks for your reply,  I have added image of desire result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this in power query using these steps:

1. Add a new column "NextSequence" = [Sequence]+1
2. Do a nested join with the table itsself, linking {"RoutID", "Sequence"} with {"RoutID", "NextSequence"} and when expanding, only keep the departedTime and ZipCode olumns calling them something like "prevDepTime" and "PrevZip"
3. write an IF-statement saying that `if [PrevZip] <> null and [PrevZip] = [ZipCode] and [ArrivedTime]-[PrevDepTime] >= #time(1,0,0) then "Late" else "OK"`
4. Clean up the table, keeping only the columns you want.

Then when loading the new table into power bi I have something that looks like this (I added a ew stops on RoutID2 for testing):

[image]

My M-code:

```
AddNextSequence = Table.AddColumn(PREVIOUS_STEP_NAME, "NextSequence", each [Sequence]+1, Int64.Type),
NestedJoin = Table.NestedJoin(AddNextSequence, {"RouteID", "Sequence"}, AddNextSequence, {"RouteID", "NextSequence"}, "AddedTable", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
ExpandTable = Table.ExpandTableColumn(NestedJoin, "AddedTable", {"DepartedTime", "ZipCode"}, {"PrevDepTime", "PrevZip"}),
Add_OkLate = Table.AddColumn(Expandedtable, "OK_or_Late", each if [PrevZip] <> null and [PrevZip] = [ZipCode] and Number.From([ArriveedTime]) - Number.From([PrevDepTime]) > Number.From(#time(1,0,0) ) then "Late"
else 
"OK", type text),
FinalizeTable = Table.SelectColumns(AddOkLate,{"RowNumber", "RouteID", "Sequence", "ArriveedTime", "DepartedTime", "ZipCode", "OK_or_Late"})
in
    FinalizeTable
```

Comment: Hi Oscar , thanks for you quick reply, Can you write where I have to write IF statement. I tried in Conditional Column creation but there is no AND statement. Appriciate your effort  , please explian where i write it. thanks

Comment: If you open the advanced editor (home tab, next to the preview refresh button) in power query and appending the code I provided only substituting PREVIOUS_STEP_NAME in the first row for the actual name of the previous step the code should work, providing I haven't made any spelling mistakes in the column names. 
Or if you do all the steps your self then add a Custom column (not conditiona) and then you can use the code in 3. just copy paist it into the column editor

Comment: Hi Oscar, I found sequence duplicates in  some RouteID, So I  created Index column grouped by RouteID Order by ArrivedTIme. Now I am using Index and NextIndex Column But I am geting  error in IF statement above.

Expression.Error: We cannot apply operator < to types Time and Duration.
Details:
    Operator=<
    Left=01:00:00
    Right=0.01:34:06 

I Used M function Time.From  but still error. I appriciate you reply on this.

Comment: I usualy use Number.From() when comparing time or dateTime values. Does that help you?

Comment: Thank yes it removed error but for Null  PrevDepTime it is still error  how to convert  null to 0? and I need to sort index by arrivalTime I am not getting it , because sequence has duplicates so I sort order by arrival time so I can map ArrivalTime and DepTime correctly . Any Idea thanks for yout time.

Comment: It becomes increaslingy more difficult to help when I can't see the code you have and the data you use. I never compare PrevDepTime to a null value, only PrevZip. Maybe that helps??